# Asynchronous method call with parameters in 1.1 .Net

Tags: c#, .net, .net-1.1

I have a method that takes a long time and I would like to call the method asynchronously and continue, I do not need a callback or error.

I have used `MethodInvoker` and `BeginInvoke` and this works fine but I can't figure out how to pass parameters?

This works without params

```
MethodInvoker me = new MethodInvoker(my method);
me.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a 5+ year old version of the .NET Framework which is compared to .NET Framewore 2.0 missing a great deal of features?

Comment: it's an old system that were making some changes to. Too much work at the moment to upgrade.

Comment: You might want to show us what you've tried so far, not just mention it.

Comment: added what I have tried. Dont know how to pass params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `MethodInvoker` in this instance?  Make your own delegate and use it:

```
public delegate MyMethodDelegate(int param1, string param2);
```

...

```
MyMethodDelegate me = new MyMethodDelegate(my method);
me.BeginInvoke(param1, param2, null, null);
```

Ta-da!

Answer (score 2):

Use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. This is ideal for "fire and forget" scenarios where you don't need a callback.

You can pass parameters like this:

```
object parameters = new object[] { 3.7, "foo", 1 };
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Blah), parameters);

...

void Blah(object state)
{
   object[] arguments = (object[])state;
   double first = (double) arguments[0];
   string second = (string) arguments[1];
   int third = (int) arguments[2];
}
```